# CE 1.9.2 - Onepage checkout - merge shipping address and method into one step

Tags: onepage-checkout, shipping-methods, shipping-address, ce-1.9.2.4

I am struggling to find a way to combine the Shipping Address and Shipping method into a single step on the default Magento Onepage Checkout. I know that there are many 3rd-party One**Step**Checkout extensions (some of which I have used in the past), but I prefer the flow of the onepage checkout...I would just like to optimise it.

Ideally, I would like to prompt for Shipping Address and Shipping Method in the first step, followed by prompting the customer for their billing address (if different) and payment information together in a single step as well. We only have 2 shipping methods which are not determined by shipping address, so there will be no need to make any ajax calls to update the available shipping methods.

I know that checkout is difficult to customise in this regard, but I would sincerely appreciate any pointers and/or advice please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Solution:

**Step: 1**

Override Controller: `\app\code\local\Htech\Checkout\controllers\OnepageController.php`

```
require_once Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php';


class Htech_Checkout_OnepageController extends Mage_Checkout_OnepageController{

/**
 * Save checkout billing address
 */
public function saveBillingAction()
{
    if ($this->_expireAjax()) {
        return;
    }
    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost('billing', array());
        $customerAddressId = $this->getRequest()->getPost('billing_address_id', false);

        if (isset($data['email'])) {
            $data['email'] = trim($data['email']);
        }
        $result = $this->getOnepage()->saveBilling($data, $customerAddressId);

        if (!isset($result['error'])) {
            if ($this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->isVirtual()) {
                $result['goto_section'] = 'payment';
                $result['update_section'] = array(
                    'name' => 'payment-method',
                    'html' => $this->_getPaymentMethodsHtml()
                );
            } elseif (isset($data['use_for_shipping']) && $data['use_for_shipping'] == 1) {
                $result['goto_section'] = 'shipping_method';
                $result['update_section'] = array(
                    'name' => 'shipping-method',
                    'html' => $this->_getShippingMethodsHtml()
                );

                //$result['allow_sections'] = array('shipping');
                //$result['duplicateBillingInfo'] = 'true';
            } else {
                $result['goto_section'] = 'shipping_method';
            }
        }

        $this->_prepareDataJSON($result);
    }
}
}
```

**Step: 2**

Create Config file:`\app\code\local\Htech\Checkout\etc\config.xml`

Block: `\app\code\local\Mage\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Abstract.php`
Copy Abstract.php from core and change  `_getStepCodes()` method to following

```
protected function _getStepCodes()
{
    return array('login', 'billing', 'shipping_method', 'payment', 'review');
}
```

**Step: 3**

Change Layout: `\app\design\frontend\rwd\default\layout\checkout.xml`

Remove/Comment All Block with `shipping.phtml` file form `checkout_onepage_index` and `checkout_onepage_progress`

i.e.

- `<block type="checkout/onepage_progress" name="shipping.progress" template="checkout/onepage/progress/shipping.phtml"></block>`
- `<block type="checkout/onepage_shipping" name="checkout.onepage.shipping" as="shipping" template="checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml" />`
- `<block type="checkout/onepage_progress" name="shipping.progress" template="checkout/onepage/progress/shipping.phtml"></block>`

**Step: 4**

Template: `\app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\checkout\onepage.phtml`

Add This code After `<div class="step-title">....</div>`

`<div id="checkout-step-<?php echo $_stepId ?>" class="step a-item" style="display:none;">
            <?php if($_stepId=='shipping_method'){ ?>
                <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('checkout/onepage_shipping')->setTemplate('checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml($_stepId) ?>
        </div>`

If Some one have short mehtod for this then share.

Output:

[image: Output]